# How do you keep html semantically correct and and handle big css of complex designs like Big portals or News sites?

Tags: css, xhtml, accessibility, semantic-markup

In personal and small business websites it's not so difficult but when we comes to New sites,Portals and E-commerce sites, where so many content comes on each pages, it's little hard.

**How do you keep **HTML** semantically correct and and handle big **CSS** of complex designs like Big portals or News sites?**

**How to keep the HTML code semantically correct and Semantic naming convention for css classes and ID?**

**Is to use CSS grid Framework the best way to handle CSS in this scenario?**

[image]

Comment: You're asking too many questions. Try narrow it down a little, you might be able to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

While in general you'll want to avoid "div soup", div and span have no meaning, and there's no reason you can't use them liberally in *addition* to "semantically correct" HTML if they help you organize.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is to create  and then float them right or left . Specify their width . Hence when you try to open them in different browsers they will be aligned properly or if you try to access them in very low or high resolution still they are perfectly aligned . Basically you need to create a nested structure so that all your corresponding elements are aligned respectively .

Answer (score 0):

For scaling and flexibility I would recommend using [Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), its scaffolding feature  will give your news site 4 responsive variations which is excellent for phone iPad etc. May take a while to learn and implement but you'll be glad you did it when you see the final results ;)